# Ion segment button styling

Tags: ionic-framework

I've created a **ion segment tabs** using ion segment button for an Android device. Below is my code

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-segment color="primary">
    <ion-segment-button value="call">
      <ion-label>Call</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="favorite">
      <ion-label>Favorite</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="map">
      <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-content>
```

Below is the output view image that I got,

[image]

But I want the output to be something like below image with the tab background color on click.

[image]

Please help me how can I get that for an android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing is default iOS segment.

Add property mode="ios" to ion-segment.

You can apply styles on ion-segment-button.

Documentation: [Segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment) [Segment Button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button)

```
<ion-segment mode="ios">
    <ion-segment-button value="one" checked>
        One
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button>
        Two
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button>
        Three
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```